# Solution for $\ln{(x-1)}+\ln{(x-2)}=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

please check solution, for this assingment. Thans.

$$
\ln{(x-1)}+\ln{(x-2)}=3\\
\text{adding two ln}\\
\ln{((x-1)*(x-2))}=3\\
(x-1)*(x-2)=e³\\
x²-2x-x+2=e³\\
x²-3x+2-e³=0\\
\text{quadratic equation where: a=1, b=-3, c=2-e³}\\
\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b²-4ac}}{2a}\\
\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-4*1*(2-e³)}}{2*1}\\
\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-8+4e³}}{2}\\
x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{1+4e³}}{2}\\
\text{so now I have that this is the final equation. Is this right???}
$$
Thanks???

Comment: I don't see anything wrong... Do you have any questions?

Comment: Your work looks okay. Bear in mind that neither $x-1$ nor $x-2$ should be negative, so you may need the discard one of the two solutions to the quadratic equation you solved.

Comment: What's wrong with $x - 1$ or $x - 2$ negative? The problem didn't say to only look at real solutions.

Comment: When using log of negative numbers or complex numbers, one can't talk of *the* log in a way that is consistent.

Comment: You would assume that the problem is talking about $Log(z)$ in that case? But I see what you mean, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, not yet! By the domain of the natural logarithm, $x>
2$.  So you have to verify whether your solutions are greater than $2$. If one of them is not, then you should discard it.

Comment: one of them is $\approx +6$ and the other $\approx -3$. So reject the negative solution.